# Enable/Disable Form by Input

Tags: javascript

I have two input forms. When they are loaded into the browser with default values, the forms are disabled.

I have created a script function that enables the input forms `onclick`. The user can then change the values in either of those forms.

As long as the value in any of the form is not the default value, both forms must remain enabled. If the user changes both the value in the input form so that it is back to its default value, then the forms will be disabled automatically again.

---

The problem here is that both the input values must **not** equal the default value for the forms to remain enabled. I'm struggling to fix this.

```js
function enable() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row")
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].disabled = false;
  }
}

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row")

function check() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].value == x[i].defaultValue) {
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="enable()">
      <input class="row" type="text" value="click me" disabled onblur="check()">
      <input class="row" type="text" value="click me2" disabled onblur="check()">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is the second `var  x` outside the function? Why no var in the loop: `for (var i=...` ? Why is the onclick on the cell instead of the fields? There are not two forms, but two fields. Also test input.defaultValue

Comment: Hi, i originally had var x inside the function, but tried playing around with the position to see if it affected anything. For (var i=... thanks, i'll keep that it mind when making loops from now on. The onclick is on the cell, because if it was inside <input >, the disabled nature of the input will not allow the event to trigger. 

i'm not quite what you mean by input.defaultValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function enable() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row")
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].disabled = false;
  }
}

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row")

function check() {
  var edited=false;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].value != x[i].defaultValue) {
      edited=true;
    }
  }
  if(edited)return;
  for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
     x[i].disabled=true;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="enable()">
      <input class="row" type="text" value="click me" disabled onblur="check()">
      <input class="row" type="text" value="click me2" disabled onblur="check()">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So you mean something like this?

EDIT:
So what we do is create a boolean which will keep track of any changes. You did some strange things with nested loops, which isn't really necessary. 
If there is a change detected, edited will be true. If they are both the same, the default value of edited will be used (false).

After the first for-loop, we check if edits have been made `if(edited)` If an edited has been made, we use return to break out of the function. You could also use:

```
if(!edited){
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
         x[i].disabled=true;
    }
}
```

But I think using return is a bit cleaner.
So if no edits have been made (the default value is entered), the code will continue and disable all fields.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much bro. This is exactly what i'm looking for. Though, i dont really understand the "edited" thingy. Could you briefly explain the code please?

Comment: Hi Hespen, thanks for your explanation. One question though, why do we only have to write if(edited) return;  and not if(edited==true) return;  How does the code know whether we are looking for false or true?

Comment: An if-statement checks if something is true or false. So `intValue==2` will return true or false depending on the `intValue` value. A boolean like `edited` however, already is `true` or `false`. You could rename the boolean to `isEdited`, so the if-statement will look like `if(isEdited)`, which is also really easy to read for other people.

Comment: I understand now. THanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is:

http://jsfiddle.net/rgghoham/

```
<span style="position:relative;">
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; cursor: pointer;" ></div>
</span>
<span style="position:relative;">
  <input type="text" disabled />
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; cursor: pointer;" ></div>
</span> 

<script>
$("div").click(function (evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you testing the default value ? Read the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility.
I took the liberty of removing the for loop as it seems you have a set number of inputs. If you choose to go that way, then it's to be applied to the enable/distable functions. Calling enable() or disable() might make it more readable, too.

```
//declare default values here (optional)
    var default1 = "click me",
        default2 = "click me2";

//enable...
        function enable() {
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row")
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].disabled = false;
          }
        }

//disable...
        function disable() {
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row")
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].disabled = true;
          }
        }


        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("row")
        function check() {
          if (x[0].value == default1 && x[1].value == default2) {     //testing your conditions
            return disable();
          } else {
            return enable();
          }

        }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. This is also a viable solution but i will be dealing with many input values in the real environment, and not just two. Thanks anyway bro.